# jQuery continuosly detect DIV distance from top

Tags: jquery

I am trying to start some animations only when the DIV is visible in the page.

This is the function I have done:

```
function startAnimations() {

    if (animated_contents)
        jQuery.each(animated_contents, function(index, arr) {
            var item = jQuery('#' + arr[1]);
            var page_id = arr[0];
            setInterval(function() {
                var visible_window = jQuery(window.top).height();
                var top = item.offset().top - jQuery(document).scrollTop();
                console.log(item + visible_window + top);
                if (top < visible_window)
                    animateEl(arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]);
            }, 500);
        })
}
```

It works. The problem is that the `setInterval` has to run always and I am afraid it will reduce the resources sensibly.
Is there a better way?
Please consider that the items are created dinamically so it must be a continuos check.
Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$(window).scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and check the position of the div to run the animation.

Comment: I tried several times but it does not work. It does not check continuosly. Maybe I should bind the scroll event to each different item. What do u think?